# Recommended resources for RSS readers?

Tags: rss, rss-reader

all. Anyone have any readings, guides, tutorials, or resources that they *particularly* recommend for RSS -- especially for going about the task of building an RSS reader?

Comment: https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as my question landed with a thud, I thought I'd share what I found myself from a little digging, for whoever comes along next.

First off, there are the tutorials offered at http://www.w3schools.com/rss/. The stuff from W3C is always useful, in my experience.

I also offer up this list of books and guides that are either about RSS directly or discuss it at some length:

- RSS and Atom in Action: Web 2.0 Building Blocks (Manning)
- Java and XML (O'Reilly)
- Beginning Java Server Pages (Wrox -- includes a discussion of Java's ROME framework)
- Developing Feeds with RSS and Atom (O'Reilly)

You can tell from the above that I was searching specifically for RSS as it relates to Java. But I also found resources about building RSS readers with [Python](http://python.about.com/od/cgiformswithpython/ht/RSSRdrMaster.htm) and [PHP](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Creating-an-RSS-Reader-the-Reader/). Of course there is lots more out there relating to Android, iOS and the like.

I hope the above will be helpful, but if anyone has any further and better resources, how-tos, and guides they recommend, please add them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to what i have gathered so far,there aren't many resources on rss readers.Apparently readers use polling to track updates.issues of etiquette have emerged in all articles i have come across but none of all articles explains it like this post:

[policy for polling rss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939642/policy-for-polling-rss)